# SSRS overlapping a number with a line to display a discountprice

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm trying to display a discountprice in my SSRS report. This means that the original price should be strikethrough. Like following example: 
[image]

How can I let my line in SSRS overlap with my number? Now the two elemens are shown among eachother.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use strikethrough like this:

[image: Strike Through Textbox - SSRS]